# Как удалить повторяющиеся элементы из Set?

Tags: java, коллекции

У меня есть Set c словами, например:

```
{
    "hello",
    "what",
    "is",
    "Is",
    "b",
    "B"
};
```

Вопрос как мне удалить повторяющиеся элементы?
Чтобы в Set у меня было `{ "hello", "what", "is", "b" }`.

Comment: Как вы пытались решать задачу? Покажите код, мы его починим.

Comment: привести все элементы к нижнему/верхнему регистру?

Comment: Stanislav пока что думаю, в голову никаких идей не приходит.

Comment: azlov не мне надо удалить повторяющиеся элементы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Set` хранит только уникальные значения, поэтому после того, как вы приведете все элементы к нижнему регистру (например), одинаковых значений не будет:

```
set = set.stream().map(String::toLowerCase).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: Спасибо!
Подскажите пожалуйста какой-нибудь ресурс для изучения Stream API.